# Set focus on selected checkbox list item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to achieve a search function for a checkbox list that i have. Upon typing in the search text, it will set focus on the item in the checkbox list (preferably not through JavaScript).

Below is what i have for the design source.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
   <br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchCountry" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a country"/>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
   <br />
   <div style="OVERFLOW-Y:scroll; WIDTH:100%; HEIGHT:115px">
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkCountry" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" Height="35px" class="form-control"></asp:CheckBoxList>
   </div>
```

Followed by my vb code.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To chkCountry.Items.Count - 1

        If InStr(chkCountry.Items(i).Value.Trim(), txtSearchCountry.Text.Trim()) = True Then


        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

With the code, i am able to find and match the search text. However, how am i able to set the focus to the item in the checkbox list?

Comment: You cannot do this without javascript, as javascript is the only way you can access your HTML DOM tree.
Reading the question again, it seems you wish to perform this synchronously instead of asynchronously. You may want to reconsider that

Comment: Your VB code won't run on the client. Also, you don't need the "= True" since it's implied.

Comment: Hi @Malky.Kid, thank you for your reply. That is not my full code, and it is only the area where i faced problem. The panel is in an update Panel, and the search will only occur if user hits enter button.

Comment: @TanStanley But if you can implement same functionality from front then why should you even consider doing it by your back-end code?. As you want to implement functionality on button click then also you can do it by using javascript. So better you prefer to do it on front.